# Programmatically create a web site in IIS using C# and set port number

Tags: c#, iis, iis-6, port

We have been able to create a web site. We did this using the information in this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525598.aspx

However, we would like to use a port number other that port 80. How do we do this?

We are using IIS 6

Comment: What IIS version are you using?

Comment: you want to specify the port during the setup or you want to add the website to IIS by code?

Comment: @Wael Add the web site to IIS and at the same time specify the port number ofthat web site.

Comment: You can check this link. It has full code and instruction. Just make sure your opening visual studio and others in administrator mode.
https://www.asptricks.net/2016/08/how-to-host-website-programmatically-in.html

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you're using IIS 7, there is a new managed API called [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://blogs.msdn.com/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/MicrosoftWebAdministration.aspx)

An example from the above blog post:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
iisManager.Sites.Add("NewSite", "http", "*:8080:", "d:\\MySite");
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

If you're using IIS 6 and want to do this, it's more complex unfortunately.

You will have to create a web service on every server, a web service that handles the creation of a website because direct user impersonation over the network won't work properly (If I recall this correctly).

You will have to use Interop Services and do something similar to this (This example uses two objects, server and site, which are instances of custom classes that store a server's and site's configuration):

```
string metabasePath = "IIS://" + server.ComputerName + "/W3SVC";
DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath, server.Username, server.Password);

string serverBindings = ":80:" + site.HostName;
string homeDirectory = server.WWWRootPath + "\\" + site.FolderName;


object[] newSite = new object[] { site.Name, new object[] { serverBindings }, homeDirectory };

object websiteId = (object)w3svc.Invoke("CreateNewSite", newSite);

// Returns the Website ID from the Metabase
int id = (int)websiteId;
```

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524569.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly we are using IIS 6.

Comment: I did this in a legacy maintenance project once, I'll see whether I can find the code. It's pretty arcane and convoluted unfortunately.

Comment: Great... btw watch out for App Pools... there might be need for some additional configuration...

Comment: Since the above link is no longer valid, here are the links to [the namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet), [Article 1 - How to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration), [Article 2 - Provisioning and Managing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/microsoftwebadministration)

Answer (score 15):

Heres the solution.
[Blog article : How to add new website in IIS 7](http://startcoding.in/2012/01/24/how-to-add-new-website-into-iis-programatically-using-asp-net-c/)

On Button click :

```
try
 {
  ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
  string strWebsitename = txtwebsitename.Text; // abc
  string strApplicationPool = "DefaultAppPool";  // set your deafultpool :4.0 in IIS
  string strhostname = txthostname.Text; //abc.com
  string stripaddress = txtipaddress.Text;// ip address
  string bindinginfo = stripaddress + ":80:" + strhostname;

  //check if website name already exists in IIS
    Boolean bWebsite = IsWebsiteExists(strWebsitename);
    if (!bWebsite)
     {
        Site mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add(strWebsitename.ToString(), "http", bindinginfo, "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\yourWebsite");
        mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = strApplicationPool;
        mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Enabled = true;
        mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Directory = "C:\\inetpub\\customfolder\\site";
        serverMgr.CommitChanges();
        lblmsg.Text = "New website  " + strWebsitename + " added sucessfully";
     }
     else
     {
        lblmsg.Text = "Name should be unique, " + strWebsitename + "  is already exists. ";
     }
   }
  catch (Exception ae)
  {
      Response.Redirect(ae.Message);
   }
```

---

Looping over sites whether name already exists

```
    public bool IsWebsiteExists(string strWebsitename)
    {
        Boolean flagset = false;
        SiteCollection sitecollection = serverMgr.Sites;
        foreach (Site site in sitecollection)
        {
            if (site.Name == strWebsitename.ToString())
            {
                flagset = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flagset = false;
            }
        }
        return flagset;
    }
```

Comment: Only for IIS7.. Cannot find reference for IIS6

Comment: To check IsWebsiteExists please see my answer. That can be more smarter way

Comment: @AdamDrewery Not helpful. Where he works may require it.

Comment: @LiakatHossain Although I prefer your lambda style, it is exactly the same logic.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following Code to Know the unUsed PortNo

```
        DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC");

        // Find unused ID PortNo for new web site
        bool found_valid_port_no = false;
        int random_port_no = 1;

        do
        {
            bool regenerate_port_no = false;
            System.Random random_generator = new Random();
            random_port_no = random_generator.Next(9000,15000);

            foreach (DirectoryEntry e in root.Children)
            {
                if (e.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
                {

                    int site_id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Name);
                    //For each detected ID find the port Number 

                     DirectoryEntry vRoot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" + site_id);
                     PropertyValueCollection pvcServerBindings = vRoot.Properties["serverbindings"];
                     String bindings = pvcServerBindings.Value.ToString().Replace(":", "");
                     int port_no = Convert.ToInt32(bindings);

                     if (port_no == random_port_no)
                    {
                        regenerate_port_no = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            found_valid_port_no = !regenerate_port_no;
        } while (!found_valid_port_no);

        int newportId = random_port_no;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have gone though all answer here and also tested. Here is the most clean smarter version of answer for this question. However this still cant work on IIS 6.0. so IIS 8.0 or above is required.

```
string domainName = "";
string appPoolName = "";
string webFiles = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\New Folder";
if (IsWebsiteExists(domainName) == false)
{
    ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
    iisManager.Sites.Add(domainName, "http", "*:8080:", webFiles);
    iisManager.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;
    iisManager.CommitChanges();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name Exists already"); 
}


public static bool IsWebsiteExists(string strWebsitename)
{
    ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
    Boolean flagset = false;
    SiteCollection sitecollection = serverMgr.Sites;
    flagset = sitecollection.Any(x => x.Name == strWebsitename);
    return flagset;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This simplified method will create a site with default binding settings, and also create the application pool if needed:

```
public void addIISApplication(string siteName, string physicalPath, int port, string appPoolName)
{
    using (var serverMgr = new ServerManager())
    {
        var sitecollection = serverMgr.Sites;
        if (!sitecollection.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == siteName.ToLower()))
        {
            var appPools = serverMgr.ApplicationPools;
            if (!appPools.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == appPoolName.ToLower()))
            {
               serverMgr.ApplicationPools.Add(appPoolName);
            }

            var mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add(siteName, physicalPath, port);
            mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;
            serverMgr.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In properties of site select "Web Site" tab and specify TCP Port.
2. In studio to debug purpose specify  http://localhost:<port>/<site&gt; at tab Web for "Use Local IIS Web Server"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is how you do it using the UI, I need to know how to do it in code.

Comment: Can you use wmi over JScript or VBScript ?