# Is there any way to create an application pool in IIS manager using c#?

Tags: iis

Can anyone help create an Application Pool in IIS using C#?

Once this has been done, how do I assign the Application Pool to a virtual directory, again using C#?

Answer (score 12):

**If you're using IIS7:**

To create an application pool using and set the .NET Framework version (to v2.0 in this case), do this:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
...

using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  ApplicationPool newPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add("MyNewPool");
  newPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v2.0";
  serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

You should add a reference to `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` which can be found in:

> `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\InetSrv`

To assign a virtual directory to an application pool (though I think you mean an application):

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  // Find Default Website
  Site site = serverManager.Sites.First(s => s.Id == 1);
  Application newApp = site.Applications.Add("/MyNewApp", 
                                               @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mynewapp");
  newApp.ApplicationPoolName = "MyNewPool";
  serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

**If you're using IIS6:**

```
using (DirectoryEntry appPools = 
                   new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools"))
{
  using (DirectoryEntry newPool = appPools.Children.Add("MyNewPool", 
                                                    "IIsApplicationPool"))
  {
    // Just use NetworkService as pool account
    newPool.Properties["AppPoolIdentityType"].Value = 2;
    newPool.CommitChanges();
  }
}
```

The following code creates an application called `MyNewApp` in the *Default Web Site* and assigns it to the application pool `MyNewPool` we created using the code example above:

```
using (DirectoryEntry siteRoot = 
         new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/1/root"))
{
  using (DirectoryEntry newApp = 
          siteRoot.Children.Add("MyNewApp", "IIsWebVirtualDir"))
  {
    newApp.Properties["Path"].Value = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mynewapp";
    newApp.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;
    newApp.Properties["AccessFlags"].Value = 513; // AccessScript | AccessRead
    newApp.Properties["AuthFlags"].Value = 7;// AuthAnonymous|AuthBasic|AuthNTLM
    newApp.Properties["AppIsolated"].Value = "2";
    newApp.Properties["AppRoot"].Value = 
                       newApp.Path.Replace("IIS://Localhost", "/LM");
    newApp.Properties["AppPoolId"].Value = "MyNewPool";
    newApp.Properties["AppFriendlyName"].Value = "MyNewApp";
    newApp.CommitChanges();
  }
}
```

I all of the above cases your code needs to be running as an administrator.

For more information see:

**IIS7:**

> [IIS 7 Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference)
>   [How to Use Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/)

**IIS6:**

> [Using System.DirectoryServices to Configure IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
>   [IIS Programmatic Administration Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524713%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
>   [IIS Metabase Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525644%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on which version of IIS you are using but check out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525598.aspx (example is for IIS7)

Source was from another question: [Programmatically create a web site in IIS using C# and set port number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1286831/217440)