# Ways of Installing a WebSite in IIS without manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, iis-7, installation

What are the different ways of installing a WebSite/Application?
One way is using WebSetup Project adding that application.
Is there any way which can programmitically do that?
Also please  let me know how can we use AssemblyInstaller class?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286831/programatically-create-a-web-site-in-iis-using-c-sharp-and-set-port-number

Answer (score 1):

I think [web deploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) might be what you need?

From The Gu: "Microsoft Web Deploy – which is a free server technology that enables a comprehensive publishing and deployment mechanism.  Web Deploy enables you to not only publish files – but also provision database schema/data, run database change scripts, set security ACLs, and more.  All of these deployment steps can be automated using Visual Studio."

Comment: in all my experiences with WebDeploy (unless it changed in 2.0) you needed to have the website created prior to publishing your site

Comment: Good point Anthony, I think you are right there. Perhaps a two stage process with Powershell first [ http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/ ] then webdeploy will provide a more complete solution.