# Create a setup for website in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, installation

I have created a website in Visual studio 2010 Express.
Now I want to create a setup file(.exe or .msi) for it so that it can be installed on the local IIS server. I am not intended to post this website online i.e. on Internet. I just want to use it on local  machines which are connected in LAN.
It is my first website and I am unaware of creating setup process in Visual Studio.

```
 if( Can I able to create a setup file of a website? )
 { 
    How?  
 }  
 else  
 {
    if(Should I have to convert it into a web application?  )
    {
        What are the steps to create setup of web application so as 
        to run it on local computers? 
    }  
 }
```

Sorry for bad representation, but I didn't know how to put my questions into words.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a few months ago, and I found this post quite useful: [Programmatically create a web site in IIS using C# and set port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286831/programatically-create-a-web-site-in-iis-using-c-sharp-and-set-port-number). It will show you how to create an IIS 7 record using C# code.

One way you might use this information to create a .exe is to create a separate application that will create the IIS 7 record and copy the files from your website directory source to your new location.

You also mention about a web application in your question - it is quite easy to deploy this type of web site and you can [find deployment instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this method.

I feel that this can be done in a few different ways, and you might find that you need to use some google skills to find what is most suitable.